# Find Limit : $\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac {1}{xe^{x}}$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

If I'm doing everything correctly, I get to 1/(-∞×0) where -∞×0 is undefined, so I don't know what to do. Also, I cannot do a series expansion because x is approaching infinity.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome. Try L'Hopital's rule on $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$

Comment: Perform the change of variable $x=-t$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As written, both factors in the denominator grow arbitrarily large and the limit is $0$. If you mean $e^x/x = 1/(xe^{-x}$ you need to think about which factor grows faster. That's clearly $e^x$.

Comment: @FShrike Doesn't L'Hopital's rule apply when x is approaching a number and not infinity? I realize I don't know much, I'm working to figure it all out

Comment: @MihailoMitrović There are versions of L'Hopital for limits at infinity

Answer (score 1):

> using l'Hopital Rule

Let :$$ t = -x \implies t \to +∞$$
$$\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac {1}{xe^{x}}=\lim_{t\to＋∞}\frac {1}{-te^{－t}}＝\lim_{t\to＋∞}－\frac {e^{t}}{t}=\lim_{t\to＋∞}－e^{t}=-∞$$